# Extend social pipeline and prevent a specific function to run during tests

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-testing, python-social-auth

I'm using [Python Django Social Auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html) and extended the pipeline with the following three steps

1. One before the user is created ([partial pipeline](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#partial-pipeline)) requesting some data.
2. One for the user creation (overrides the `social.pipeline.user.create_user` method).
3. One after the user is created.

Here's how the [pipeline](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#personalized-configuration) currently looks like

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'myapp.file.before_user_is_created',
    'myapp.file.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'myapp.file.after_user_creation',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

---

In order to test it, I'm following [similar logic to the one used here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/master/tests/test_views.py#L29). This is what I have

```
@mock.patch("social_core.backends.base.BaseAuth.request")
def test_complete(self, mock_request):
        url = reverse("social:complete", kwargs={"backend": "facebook"})
        url += "?code=2&state=1"
        mock_request.return_value.json.return_value = {"access_token": "123"}
        with mock.patch(
            "django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase" ".set_expiry",
            side_effect=[OverflowError, None],
        ):
            response_1 = self.client.get(url)
            self.assertEqual(response_1.status_code, 302)
            self.assertEqual(response_1.url, "/before-user-is-created/")

            response_2 = self.client.post("/before-user-is-created/", {"some_keys": "some_values"})
            self.assertEqual(response_2.status_code, 302)
            self.assertEqual(response_2.url, "/social-auth/complete/facebook/")

            response_3 = self.client.post("/social-auth/complete/facebook/")
            return response_3
```

For step 1, I have a url (`/before-user-is-created/`) and a specific view. So, I get that view and I'm able to act on it when running

```
response_1 = self.client.get(url)
```

as you can see from the `self.assertEqual(response_1.url, "/before-user-is-created/")` and from `response_2 = self.client.post("/before-user-is-created/", {"some_keys": "some_values"})`.

The problem is with step 3. That is essentially a function (`after_user_creation()`) that calls another one (`function_called()`)

```
def after_user_creation(user, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    function_called(something_from_user)
```

That function is called in this part during the test (together with `load_extra_data` and `user_details` (the ones coming after it in the pipeline))

```
response_2 = self.client.post("/before-user-is-created/", {"some_keys": "some_values"})
...
response_3 = self.client.post("/social-auth/complete/facebook/")
...
```

How to prevent `function_called(something_from_user)` to run during tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch `myapp.file.function_called` as usual:

```py
with mock.patch(
    "django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase" ".set_expiry",
    side_effect=[OverflowError, None],
), mock.patch("myapp.file.function_called"):
```

Alternatively:

```py
@mock.patch("myapp.file.function_called")
@mock.patch("social_core.backends.base.BaseAuth.request")
def test_complete(self, mock_request, mock_function_called):
```